# Can you simulate a continuous signal with gaussian noise using a noiseless discrete channel?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, information-theory, coding-theory, noise

It is well known that you can communicate a discrete signal via a continuous but noisy one (see the [noisy channel coding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noisy-channel_coding_theorem)). My question is, can you do the opposite in the case of gaussian noise?

Given any $r \in \mathbb R_+$, does there exist $n \in \mathbb N$ (the number of discrete levels) and independent random functions $e : [0, r) \to \{0, 1, \dots, n\}$ (the encoding function) and $d : \{0, 1, \dots, n\} \to \mathbb R$ (the decoding function) such that:

$$d(e(x)) \sim \mathcal{N}(r, 1)$$

for all $x \in [0, r)$?

In other words, can we communicate a real number in the range from $0$ to $r$ using a discrete channel, such that the noise is the standard normal distribution.

I am guessing the minimum possible $n$ to be approximately proportional to $r$.

Comment: I don't think this can work: the (Shannon, not differential) entropy of any continuous noise is infinite, while because you're passing through a symbol set of finite size, the entropy of $d(e(x))$ must be finite. So this shouldn't work for any $n < \infty$ (even for countably infinite encodings you should still suffer the same sort of issue, although this might take some work to show). Of course, approximations to the Gaussian law are possible.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 you are forgetting that $d$ is also random, and could contain infinite entropy. You argument shows that $d$ *must* have infinite entropy.

Comment: What do you mean by "a continuous signal with gaussian noise"? Noise is (typically) considered as part/effect/property of the channel, not part of the signal. Maybe you mean "a continuous signal whose (marginal) distribution is Gaussian"? If so, I guess the more fundamental question is whether there exists a discrete-valued random variable $d:\{0,1,\ldots,n\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $d \sim \mathcal{N}(r,1)$. I think the answer is (obviously?) no, therefore, the encoder-decoder scheme you mention is also not possible.